# Grails Spring Security UI RegisterController override

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I'm having a bit of bother with an upgrade of Grails 2.4.3 and Spring Security RC2... I'm probably missing something simply but any help gratefully received.

I'm overriding the RegisterController here:

```
def register(RegisterCommand command) {

    if (command.hasErrors()) {
        render view: 'index', model: [command: command]
        return
    }

    String salt = saltSource instanceof NullSaltSource ? null : command.username

    //def info = Info.findByName(command.info.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""))
    def info = Info.findByName(params.info).toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")

    def user = lookupUserClass().newInstance(email: command.email, username: command.username,
            accountLocked: true, enabled: true, info: info, location: params.location)

    RegistrationCode registrationCode = springSecurityUiService.register(user, command.password, salt)
    if (registrationCode == null || registrationCode.hasErrors()) {
        // null means problem creating the user
        flash.error = message(code: 'spring.security.ui.register.miscError')
        flash.chainedParams = params
        redirect action: 'index'
        return
    }

    String url = generateLink('verifyRegistration', [t: registrationCode.token])

    def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
    def body = conf.ui.register.emailBody
    if (body.contains('$')) {
        body = evaluate(body, [user: user, url: url])
    }
    mailService.sendMail {
        to command.email
        from conf.ui.register.emailFrom
        subject conf.ui.register.emailSubject
        html body.toString()
    }

    render view: 'index', model: [emailSent: true]
}
```

class RegisterCommand {

```
String username
String email
String password
String password2

List info = Info.findAll("from Info as d where d.name!=?", ['Super Admin']).toList()

def grailsApplication

static constraints = {
    username blank: false, validator: { value, command ->
        if (value) {
            def User = command.grailsApplication.getDomainClass(
                    SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.userDomainClassName).clazz
            if (User.findByUsername(value)) {
                return 'registerCommand.username.unique'
            }
        }
    }
    email blank: false

    password blank: false, nullable: false
    password2 validator: RegisterController.password2Validator
}
```

}

and here is the snippet of code from my GSP

```
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="selectDepartment">Info</label>
        <div class="controls form-field-pad">
            <g:select name="info" from="${command.info.name.unique()}" labelCode='Info'
                      labelCodeDefault='Info' value="${info}" noSelection="['':'-Choose your Info-']" data-trigger="change" data-required="true" data-required-message="You must select Info"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now if I strip out my additional code with references to Info then the user gets stored correctly and the email gets sent... however I'm getting the following error:

```
register.index: [action:index, controller:register]
| Error 2014-09-18 10:47:57,728 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  -  GroovyCastException occurred when processing request: [GET] /my_app/register/index
Cannot cast object 'info' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot cast object 'info' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'
Line | Method
->>   27 | index     in com.my_app.RegisterController$$EOqD2RUm
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    200 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|     53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     49 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the piece of code you posted? The error message says `Cannot cast object 'InfoDetail' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List'`and the code you posted does not contain a variable/field named `infoDetail`.

Comment: sorry that is a typo from me... corrected. I change the originally naming to protect what I'm doing

Comment: that detail could have come from the domain anyhow because it's listed it's content.

Comment: Is the `info` field inside you User class object of type `List`?

Comment: yes, so it ignores Super Admin but pulls all the other data from the table, for instance "info"